# Function call time-consuming successive decrease in a for loop

Tags: objective-c

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    double start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    iRet = func_detect(hDetect, &pImage_t, &pDetectResult, &pCount);
    iRet = func_align(hAlign, &pImage_t, &pDetectResult[0].rect, 1, &pLandMark);
    double end = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    NSLog(@"Time consuming:%lf",(end - start)*1000);
}
NSLog(@"end with pCount:%d", pCount);
```

Results:

[image]

I call a C language function in a `for` loop and time-consuming successive decrease.
First time is very long, and then each call takes will reduce, the final stable in a small range.
How to explain it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add your code here as a code block instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at `func_detect` or `func_align`, I can only assume the following:

1. Dataset is reduced by the time loop is in its 4th iteration.
2. Some kind of run time optimization is being introduced by the OS and/or Processor.